# SQL Server Transpose without Dynamic SQL and hardcoded columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I need to transpose rows into columns but I don't want to use PIVOT as it needs the columns to be pre-defined (my columns would be dynamic). So, the solution to that would be to use dynamic SQL with PIVOT but I don't want to use dynamic SQL as I would want to use the results of that SQL to join with another static SQL to generate a different result set.
What are the other options?

Here's my original SQL resultset:

```
EmpID|MonthYear|HoursWorked
10   |Jan 2013 |160
10   |Feb 2013 |150
10   |Mar 2013 |140
20   |Jan 2013 |130
20   |Feb 2013 |170
20   |Mar 2013 |155
```

and the transposed results should look like this:

```
EmpID|Jan 2013|Feb 2013|Mar 2013
10   |160     |150     |140
20   |130     |170     |155
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately if you have an unknown number of values that you want to turn into columns, you will have to use dynamic SQL.  It is required that the new columns be known when the query is executed so it must be part of the query string that you are executing.

You would need to use something similar to the following to get the list of columns that you want included in your query:

```
select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(datename(m, monthyear) + ' ' 
                                         + cast(year(monthyear) as char(4))) 
                    from yourtable
                    group by monthyear
                    order by monthyear
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')
```

Then your full script to generate the PIVOT result would be:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(datename(m, monthyear) + ' ' 
                                         + cast(year(monthyear) as char(4))) 
                    from yourtable
                    group by monthyear
                    order by monthyear
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT empid,' + @cols + ' 
            from 
            (
                select empid, 
                  datename(m, monthyear) + '' '' 
                            + cast(year(monthyear) as char(4)) monthyear, 
                  hoursworked
                from yourtable
            ) src
            pivot 
            (
                sum(hoursworked)
                for monthyear in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query);
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/71856/2)

If you want to join this result to other table, then you can easily include the JOIN in your dynamic SQL string or you could drop the result into a temp table that could be joined.